# Hide a button in SwiftUI to use its keyboardShortcut on MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have Buttons with a keyboardShortcut in my view to receive keyboardShortcuts, but I don't want the Buttons to be visible.
Ho do I hide them best?
I tried like this, but if I add `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` to the group, the buttons with the arrows don't work anymore (default and escape do).

```
import SwiftUI

struct HiddenCommandbutton: View {
  @State var showMiniDialog = false
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text("Hello, world!")
        .padding()
      Button("show"){showMiniDialog = true}
      .sheet(isPresented: $showMiniDialog){
        MiniDialog()
      }
    }
  }
}

struct MiniDialog: View {
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  @State var sel: Int?
  
  var options = ["Opt1", "Opt2", "Opt3", "Opt4"]
  var rEdge:Int { options.count-1}
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack{
      Group{
        Button(""){dismiss()}.keyboardShortcut(.cancelAction)
        Button(""){dismiss()}.keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
        Button(""){left()}.keyboardShortcut(.leftArrow)
        Button(""){right()}.keyboardShortcut(.rightArrow)
      }//.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
      .padding(0)
      HStack{
        ForEach(options.indices) { index in
          option(options[index],pos: index)
        }
        
        
      }
      
    }
    .padding(4)
  }
  
  func left(){
    if sel == nil {
      sel = rEdge
    } else if sel! > 0 {
      sel = sel! - 1
    }
  }
  
  func right(){
    if sel == nil {
      sel = rEdge
    } else if sel! < rEdge {
      sel = sel! + 1
    }
  }
  
  @ViewBuilder func option(_ title: String, pos: Int) -> some View {
    if (sel != nil && sel! == pos) {
      Text(title)
        .padding(4)
        .background(Color.red)
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
    } else {
      Text(title)
        .padding(4)
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  Group{
    Button(""){dismiss()}.keyboardShortcut(.cancelAction)
    Button(""){dismiss()}.keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
    Button(""){left()}.keyboardShortcut(.leftArrow)
    Button(""){right()}.keyboardShortcut(.rightArrow)
  }
  .opacity(0)     // << here !!
```

Comment: Interestingly, a `@State` change in such a button does not trigger a re-render for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following View extension to add an underlying, hidden button to the View hierarchy:

```
extension View {
    /// Adds an underlying hidden button with a performing action that is triggered on pressed shortcut
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - key: Key equivalents consist of a letter, punctuation, or function key that can be combined with an optional set of modifier keys to specify a keyboard shortcut.
    ///   - modifiers: A set of key modifiers that you can add to a gesture.
    ///   - perform: Action to perform when the shortcut is pressed
    public func onKeyboardShortcut(key: KeyEquivalent, modifiers: EventModifiers = .command, perform: @escaping () -> ()) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Button("") {
                perform()
            }
            .hidden()
            .keyboardShortcut(key, modifiers: modifiers)
            
            self
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used conveniently in your code like this:

```
NavigationView()
    // on cmd+W
    .onKeyboardShortcut(key: "w", modifiers: .command) {
        // hide the app
        MainPanelController.shared.windowShouldClose()
    }
```